# d3.js v4 adds transform matrix style when transform attribute is modified, preventing zoom

Tags: d3.js

Using d3 v4.13.0, I'm attempting to modify the zoom of a view container ( element). The variable `this.view` represents that element. This code is the same as it was in d3 v3, but in v4 d3.js is adding a new style attribute as well as changing the transform attribute.

This is how the view element looks before the transform attribute is modified:

```
<g class="view" data-radium="true"></g>
```

This is the code which modifies the attribute:

```
// viewTransform is a {k, x, y} transform object
const view = d3.select(this.view)
  .attr("transform", this.state.viewTransform);
```

The code above does one thing, it changes the transform attribute on the element. The result is:

```
<g 
  class="view" 
  data-radium="true" 
  transform="translate(404.3430823298754,16.377242185754085) scale(0.7710853699920492)" 
  style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></g>
```

The problem is that the style attribute is overriding the transform. How do I get d3 to stop adding the style attribute?

An alternative to using d3 of course is to simply use Vanilla JS, select the view element, and modify the transform property manually, but I want to continue to use d3. Maybe this is fixed in v5?

**Edit:** It looks like anything that adds the transform attribute also causes something to create the matrix style. I directly modified the element using Javascript (`const elem = d3.select(this.view).node().setAttribute('transform', ...)`) and the style still showed up. I had to unset the transform style for the zoom feature to work again (`elem.style.transform = null`);

Comment: I doubt that this has got anything to do with d3. Do you use any other libraries or modules apart from core d3? Can you put this into an executable demo?